Tasks concurrent management in .NET
I need to manage of many started Task by using collection for temporary task storage. I would not want to get a situation with "infinitely" growing tasks collection, where most of the tasks have already been completed! Completed task must be immediately self-removed from this collection.
At the Final point, I whant to "WaitAll" unaccomplished tasks before to continue another code.
That's all I want. And I'm looking for a ready pattern for that!
"while (..) { task.Start(); tasks.Add(task); } Task.WaitAll(tasks);" (completed task is self-removed from tasks)
This is my first post with a question on "stackoverflow" - I apologize if anything is wrong ;-)
var TaksBag = new ConcurrentDictionary<Task,byte>(); //I don’t know another standard solution for this collection

//some cyclic code begin
while (true) //For example, let be - an infinite loop
{

//First realization begin
Task tsk = null;
tsk = new Task(() => { var t = tsk; TasksBag.TryAdd(t, 0); SomeProcess(); TasksBag.TryRemove(t, out _); }); //Many “times” (points) in code
tsk.Start();
//First realization end

//or

//Perhaps this second realization is better begin 
Task tsk = new Task(() => SomeProcess());
TasksBag.TryAdd(tsk, 0);
tsk.ContinueWith((t) => TasksBag.TryRemove(t, out _), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
tsk.Start();
//Perhaps this second realization is better end

}
//some cyclic code end

//Final point
var ta = TasksBag.Keys.ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(ta);
foreach (var tsk in ta)
    TasksBag.TryRemove(tsk, out _);
    //no exception processing for simplify; not needed if only hit once to this point (GC or app exit solve this)


Is there any established pattern code for the following construction (for simplicity, I omit the cancellation pattern).
There can be two various architectural situations at the Final point:

New tasks are not added to the collection. And this point only hit once
or
New tasks can continue to be added to the collection, but should be excluded from the collection at this point. Perhaps, there will still be a new hit at this point later, and next processing "WaitAll"

Is there any generally accepted solution to such a problem? Or a simplyfy this code?
Update #1:
After thinking, I determine - this problem cannot be left without exception handling. And it does complicate the issue after "WaitAll." Tasks "not reaching their end" will remain in the task collection due to an exception (but, apparently, not in the version with "ContinueWith," but this is cunning - an exception can happen inside "ContinueWith" without deleting the task from the collection; "another question" - whether something will change when processing exceptions in "Final point" - I will not consider this) - and the completed (unsuccessful) task will not remove itself from the task collection!
var ta = TasksBag.Keys.ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(ta);
foreach (var tsk in ta)
    TasksBag.TryRemove(tsk, out _); //no exception processing for simplify; not needed if only hit once to this point (GC or app exit solve this)

Also, question text and code has been adjusted
Update #2 This is real my problem:
I parsing WEB addresses. And I whant to create each task for processing each of them. But I asked a question - to find a generally accepted pattern for solving the problem of waiting for still unaccomplished tasks (after leaving the block of their generation). When a process can generate a colossal number of (short) tasks before "WaitAll" was executed!
Also, code has been formated
Update 3:
I think, this
//First realization begin
Task tsk = null;
tsk = new Task(() => { var t = tsk; TasksBag.TryAdd(t, 0); SomeProcess(); TasksBag.TryRemove(t, out _); }); //Many “times” (points) in code
tsk.Start();
//First realization end

Has a potential big mistake here
"var t = tsk;"
If I create a lot of tasks that will not have time to quickly complete. Then they will be queued before begin start. And, by the time execution begins, what will be in the "tsk" variable? There will be a "foreign" task!!!
Therefore, its very wrong to write like that. And I don't know a direct way to get a link to the current task. True, here there are some solutions (and it seems to me that there the "best solution" has the same problem I have identified).
But... of course, in my case, the current problem can be solved somehow
var tsk = new Task(() => { var t = TasksBag.Keys.FirstOrDefault(ts => ts.Id == Task.CurrentId); SomeProcess(u); if (t is not null) TasksBag.TryRemove(t, out _); });
TasksBag.TryAdd(tsk, 0);
tsk.Start();


Would you mind to "dumb down" the requirements for me? I don't seem to be able to grasp what exactly is asked to do, here.

But meanwhile: 1. Do not use WaitAll , use await WhenAll. 2. Do not new Task(). 3. Avoid ContinueWith, instead use await ... to start with.

I have read this five times, and have no idea what you mean.

Please share a [mcve].

What is this TaksBag (sic) accomplishing exactly (and is it a bag or a dictionary)? guaranteed - new tasks are not added to the collection Huh? new tasks can continue to be added to the collection How does that not contradict point 1?

Tasks aren't threads, they represent some kind of work that will get executed by the runtime using a threadpool thread (or not, if it represents an async operation). In other languages similar types are called promises or futures. You don't need a TaskBag, the runtime itself runs tasks on threads from a threadpool.

.NET has higher-level abstractions for pub/sub, parallelism, CSP/pipeline or stream processing - all of which are built on top of tasks but all require different architectures. You can use Parallel.ForEach or Parallel LINQ to partition in-memory data and process each chunk using a different worker task automatically. You can use a Channel as a pub/sub collection between publishers and subscribers. At a higher level you can use Dataflow to construct a pipeline of independently executing blocks that pass messages between them, similar to how you combine different tools in a shell script

I am sorry, if someone did not understand my problem :_(
I updated the text of the question ,a little. The code is working. But I want to simplify it if there is some generally accepted pattern for effectively solving the problem of waiting for incomplete tasks without accumulating completed tasks

@Darklight the problem is that you're trying to treat Tasks as threads. There's rarely any need for ContinueWith when async/await is available and there's no need to manually manage tasks as if they were threads. There's no task accumulation and Task.WhenAll or WhenAny are already efficient. If you want to process a fixed number of items, you can use ActionBlock or Parallel.ForEachAsync with a specific MaxDegreeOfParallelism. If you want to control the partitioning behavior in Parallel.ForEach` or  PLINQ, you can also specify the DOP.

@Darklight what are you actually trying to do? Right now you're describing what the implementation would look like. That doesn't explain what you actually want. If you have eg 1000 URLs to scrape, you can scrape just 4 at a time by using HttpClient inside Parallel.ForEachAsync with a DOP of 4 instead of the default, whic h is th number of virtual cores.

Are you trying to create a job queue perhaps? The quick&dirty way would be to create a ConcurrentQueue<Fumc<Task>>, iterate over the items and call them.. Instead of trying to manage continuations in the loop, create an async method that contains the steps you want and enqueue a lambda calling that method.

Fildor, Of course, I know about "await WhenAll". I just wrote a more classic code example for simplicity. Explain your other tips, please
Panagiotis Kanavos, I use TaskBag to wait for tasks to complete - before the following algorithm
mjwills, ConcurrentDictionary<Task,byte> TasksBag  = new ConcurrentDictionary<Task,byte>();
But I don't know better solution for this. I ask it. Two way architectural situation are not intersect solutions.

Panagiotis Kanavos, Code that generates tasks can generate millions and billions of tasks during its execution, up to infinity (this is already a hypothetical problem). I don't want to just add up their entire collection with endless accumulation, and then, when the time comes, expect from this gigantic collection that there is still unfinished. I'm looking for a more fundamental solution!
The code with "ContinueWith" is just an alternative - another code is written a little higher! I don't know what's best!

At this moment, I am really parsing WEB addresses. And I need to create "parallel" tasks for processing each of them. But I asked a general question - to find a generally accepted pattern for solving the problem of waiting for still unaccomplished tasks (after leaving the block of their generation). When a process can generate a colossal number of (short) tasks before "WaitAll" is launched!

I already explained how to handle this, and you don't need anything fancy. Just a list of URLs and Parallel.ForEachAsync. There are no uncompleted tasks to worry about, Parallel.ForEachAsync will start N worker tasks and use them to process all the URLs. No need for WhenAll at all. await Parallel.ForEach(urls,async (url,token)=>{ var html=await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url); await File.WriteAllTextAsync(someFile,html); var doc=parser.Parse(html); ....})

The point is that you don't queue the tasks, you queue the URLs and use a fixed number of worker tasks to process the URLs by calling an asynchronous method. That's how Parallel.ForEach/ForEachAsync and Dataflow blocks work.

Panagiotis Kanavos,Why you can't understand me. I'm not asking about "Parallel.ForEachAsync." I don't have an original url list. I asked a generalized question about Task, to find a ready-made pattern. If it does not exist - I already have a working code, solves my problem!
Consider that the url list is infinite

But, anticipating your answer, yes - I can put all the url generation code (or some other generalized algorithm) into an asynchronous generator (enumerator) and process its elements according to the "Parallel.ForEachAsync" pattern. But there will already be its own hassle, with other parts of the program, incl. interactive part! Therefore, I would like to fundamentally divide the place where tasks are created. And the place is where I just have to wait for the unaccomplished tasks! Before run another algorithm

Why you can't understand me on the contrary, I do. There are frequent identical questions by people that think of tasks as threads. Until you break away from this bad mental model you won't be able to understand that you don't have to control task creation. I've answered a lot of questions asking how to download, process and import tons of URLs with throttling, sometimes using Dataflow, sometimes using Channels, sometimes using Parallel.ForEachAsync. And at least one time I described how to do this with each method separately.

I perceive tasks as tasks + scheduler. I launch the task - and forget about it. In this topic, I don't even need the result of their work. And the order of execution is not important. It is only important for me - when it is necessary - to wait for the complete completion of all the tasks. But... I proceed from the assumption that up to this point a lot of tasks may arise and have time to complete! And keeping them all until the end point is not effective!

It is precisely to find a solution to such a problem that I created this question. Moreover. I even wrote a working solution - but I asked - is there a known pattern for this kind of problem!
At the same time, there are other "parallel threads" of algorithm execution - they can affect the "current thread," including transferring data to it and gently interrupting it! But this topic I do not touch
